# Building Standalone exe from VS2010 and OpenGL Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exe, release

I build release and debug version of opengl program in Visual Studio 2010. My os is Windows 8.1 Pro .
Among other things the program uses textures and the glui framework.
I can compile and run the program in VS but when i start the exe file, the window opens and is black, but nothing happens. In Visual Studio i linked to glew32.lib;glu32.lib;opengl32.lib.
In Release Mode i build with Multithreaded-DLL /MD
and in Debug Mode with Multithreaded-DLL /MDd

Comment: i excluded the glui part of my programm and changed to release /MT and debug /MTd modus. i have to copy exe, texture and glsl files in one folder and it works.

Comment: ok the solution is that i have to build the glui libs in /MT mode too.